# How does Haskell evaluate this function which undoes list intercalation?

Tags: haskell, equational-reasoning

I'm trying to understand how Haskell evalutes `sep [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to get `([1, 3], [2, 4, 5])` where:

```
sep [ ] = ([ ], [ ])
sep [x] = ([ ], [x])
sep (x1:x2:xs) = let (is, ps) = sep xs in (x1:is, x2:ps)
```

I start like this:

```
sep [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = sep [3, 4, 5] in (1:is, 2:ps)
```

but then?

Comment: next step is to match `sep [3, 4, 5]` with `sep (x1:x2:xs) = ...`

Comment: Ok, so.

1) sep [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = sep [3, 4, 5] in (1:is, 2:ps)

2) sep [3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = sep [5] in (3:is, 4:ps)

3) sep [5] = ([], [5])

In 2) sep [3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = ([], [5]) in (3:is, 4:ps).

Any idea in how to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I understood.

`1) sep [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = sep [3, 4, 5] in (1:is, 2:ps)`

`2) sep [3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = sep [5] in (3:is, 4:ps)`

`3) sep [5] = ([], [5])`

In 2) `sep [3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = ([], [5]) in (3:is, 4:ps) = ([3], [4, 5])`

In 1) `sep [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = let (is, ps) = ([3], [4, 5]) in (1:is, 2:ps) = ([1, 3], [2, 4, 5])`